# Operator Overloading (+) for adding two arrays with C++

Tags: c++

I have created this class with and operator overloading function to add two array. The program runs with no error but doesn't output anything. I believe the operator for loop gets terminated as it reaches this line: *(brandNew.ptr+i) = *(ptr +i) + *(obj2.ptr +i). could anyone help to see where the code is causing problem ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <class number>
class overloading{

public:
    int *ptr;
    int Size;

    overloading (){};
    overloading(number x[], number s){
        ptr =  &x[0];
        Size = s;
    }

    overloading operator+(overloading obj2){
        overloading brandNew;

        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++ ){

            *(brandNew.ptr+i) = *(ptr +i) + *(obj2.ptr +i) ;
        }
        return (brandNew);
    }




};


int main()
{

    int a[5] = {2,2,5,3,6};
    int b[5] = {2,3,2,1,9};

    overloading <int> obj(a, 5);
    overloading <int> obj2(b, 5);
    overloading <int> obj3;

    obj3 = obj + obj2;
    cout << obj3.ptr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're incorrectly assuming that the pointer operations in the loop magically/impliictly resize the memory pointed to by `brandNew.ptr`.   That is not the case.   If you want allocated memory to resize, it is necessary to do that EXPLICITLY.   For example, by using operator `new` to allocate a new memory block, copying existing memory to newly allocated memory, and then corresponding operator `delete` to release the old one.

Comment: There are multiple other problems too.   Fundamentally, your design is broken from a C++ perspective.   You need to read up on and learn several basics of C++, before jumping in with code like this.    As asked, every time people give a fix to one problem in your code, you'll find another problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `ptr` inside `operator+`, like this:

```
overloading operator+(overloading const &obj2){
        overloading brandNew;

        brandNew.ptr = new int[Size];  //  <- allocate memory

        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++ ){

            *(brandNew.ptr+i) = *(ptr +i) + *(obj2.ptr +i) ;
        }
        return (brandNew);
    }
```

otherwise you are accessing invalid memory at `brandNew.ptr`, which invokes undefined behavior.

Also, note that the argument to `operator+` should be a `const&`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/X4aMhm).

You should also be allocating memory in the constructors of `overloading`.